# Why mat table is not rendered?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Now i used two days on getting Mat table to work. I want to load a list of companies to the table.

bu the only thing i see is this :

[image]

There are no errors or anything, just blank. I expected at least to see a table with one column 'name'.

Here is my component and datasource :

```
    import { OnInit, Component, ChangeDetectorRef } from "@angular/core";
import { CompanyService } from "../../../../services/company.service";
import { CompanyListItem } from "../../../../models/CompanyListItem";

import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import { DataSource } from "@angular/cdk/collections";

@Component({
  selector: "company-list",
  templateUrl: "./companylist.component.html"
})
export class CompanyListComponent implements OnInit {

  companys: CompanyListDataSource = new CompanyListDataSource(this.companyService);;
  pagenumber: number = 0
  numberOfRowsPerPage: number = 25
  displayedColumns: ['Name', 'Email']

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.companyService.GetPaged(this.pagenumber, this.numberOfRowsPerPage).subscribe((succ) => {
      console.log(succ)
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
  }

}

export class CompanyListDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

  constructor(private companyService: CompanyService) {
    super();
  }

  connect(): Observable<CompanyListItem[]> {
    return this.companyService.GetPaged(0,25);
  }
  disconnect() { }
}
```

here is html for the table :

```
   <div class="">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="companys">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let company"> {{company.Name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  </div>
```

Comment: I think you need to follow the example more closely. See here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/vqpgqdldegv?file=app%2Ftable-http-example.ts. Move to the newer `MatTableDataSource`, and get away from `DataSource`. This make adding pagination and sorting easy when you get to that point.

Comment: Refer to you console errors, its probably because you didn't specify Email column

Comment: If anyone else comes across a similar issue, you may need to check if you omitted <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>. It gives a similar no-error but no display issue.

Answer (score 16):

You did not initialize your columns.

Change this:

```
displayedColumns: ['Name', 'Email']
```

to this:

```
displayedColumns = ['Name', 'Email']
```

Comment: hahaha you rock Alex D, i made the exact same error as the poster :). Really strange that it doesnt throw an error

Comment: If I could upvote this answer by thousands time :-)

Comment: i have lots of experience with Angular and Angular Material... 3 years after original post and I discovered that I did the EXACT same thing! lol. Thanks Alex D!

Comment: This didn't solve my error, but I was still missing it. So thanks